# running wagtail 4.2.2 rebuild_references_index issue

Tags: wagtail

Hi Getting issues running rebuild_references_index for my wagtail 4.2.2 app after upgrade from wagtail 2.15.* with one model only

Model is

```
class Breadcrumb(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=choices.CMS_APP_CHOICES,
        null=True,
        db_index=True
    )
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    page = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

The offending line seems to be

```
page = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

If I comment this out no issue

error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/management/commands/rebuild_references_index.py", line 52, in handle
    ReferenceIndex.create_or_update_for_object(instance)
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/models/reference_index.py", line 364, in create_or_update_for_object
    references = set(cls._extract_references_from_object(object))
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/models/reference_index.py", line 279, in _extract_references_from_object
    yield cls._get_base_content_type(model).id, str(
  File "/Users/davidurquhart/great/directory-cms/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/models/reference_index.py", line 168, in _get_base_content_type
    parents = model_or_object._meta.get_parent_list()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is new functionality added to an existing project, my first guess would be that the Breadcrumb data might not be 100% clean. My suggestion to get you past this initial problem would be to use the console or a manage command to loop over all pages in the breadcrumbs table and print their titles. I am guessing you'll find the source of `NoneType` in that output.

My longer term suggestion would be to refactor that model so it uses a regular ForeignKey to the Wagtail Page model. Then if you need to access fields from your page subclasses, you can use Wagtail's [specific](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.query.PageQuerySet.specific)

Comment: This is the source of the NoneType

Comment: This is the source of the NoneType
parents = model_or_object._meta.get_parent_list() # model_or_object is None
from reference_index.py::def _get_base_content_type(cls, model_or_object)